# SQL : move a column from one table to the other

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table, drop-table

I have SQL code that adds a new column with a default value for each row in a table in my database.

I need it to also remove that same column from another table at the same time, and I'm not sure about the syntax.

```
create procedure remove_a_column()
begin
    IF ( *some given condition* ) = 0 
    THEN
        ALTER TABLE static.new_table ADD COLUMN column_to_move smallint(6) DEFAULT 2,  ADD FOREIGN KEY (column_to_move) REFERENCES static.other_table(pk);
        <***>
    END if;
end
```

at the <***> point, I want to add the code that will delete the column `column_to_move` from the table `static.old_table`, no matter what's the value there.

Comment: ALTER TABLE "table_name" DROP "column_name";

Comment: @Randy should the keywords ALTER TABLE be written again?

Comment: yes - you are altering the other table.

Comment: @Randy and should there be a keyword 'COLUMN' before 'column name'? -->
DROP COLUMN "column_name"

Comment: that is optional - you may include it if you like.